# Why am I getting the "Must declare the table variable ..." error here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I'm getting it within the body my `AddPartner` stored procedure:

```
-- Create stored procedure for inserting a partner and returning the id of that inserted partner
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPartner (@name     NVARCHAR(50),
                             @email    NVARCHAR(254),
                             @new_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Partners (name, email)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @new_guid
    VALUES (@name, @email)
END
```

Then later I'm getting

> Could not find stored procedure 'AddPartner'.

but I'm supposing this is related the aforementioned error? I'm trying to use it so that I can get the `id` of the newly inserted item and use that to insert in a related table:

```
DECLARE @first_partner_id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

EXEC AddPartner 'Haliburton', 'DCheney@Haliburton.org', @first_partner_id OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO Partners (name, email) 
VALUES ('Berkshire Hathaway', 'WarrenBridgemaster@bershire.org');

INSERT INTO Partners (name, email) 
VALUES ('Jason', 'jason89@gmail.com');

--                  Partners 
-- ============================================================
--     id  | name                  | email
-- ============================================================
--      1  | 'Haliburton'          | 'DCheney@Haliburton.org'
--      2  | 'Berkshire Hathaway'  | 'WarrenBridgemaster@bershire.org'
--      3  | 'Jason'               | 'jason89@gmail.com'


INSERT INTO Answers (question_id, partner_id, val) 
VALUES (1, @first_partner_id, 24);

INSERT INTO Answers (question_id, partner_id, val) 
VALUES (1, @first_partner_id, 50);

INSERT INTO Answers (question_id, partner_id, val) 
VALUES (3, @first_partner_id, 90);
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Try including the schema:  `exec dbo.AddPartner . . . `.

Comment: use the error message like your title could use dynamic sql to solve it. but since you got Could not find stored procedure 'AddPartner'. i think you should try Gordon's suggestion first

Answer (score 5):

As stated in @MohammadSanati answer, `OUTPUT` can only insert into a table or table variable.

So it assumes `@new_guid` is a table variable but can't find it declared. (its declared as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not a table). Because of this your `CREATE PROC` fails.. subsequently when you try and call it it can't find it and you get 'Could not find stored procedure....

So you need to declare a table variable after your `BEGIN`, something like this:

```
DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE (AColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Then use it like this:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @OutputTable (AColumn)
```

Then load it into your output variable like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @new_guid = AColumn FROM @OutputTable
```

Note: if more than one record is generated this just picks an arbitrary one.

Comment: The `TOP` is in the wrong place: `SELECT TOP 1 @new_guid = [AColumn] FROM @OutputTable`

Comment: Oh thanks - I'll fix it. Although I think the OP has abandoned

Answer (score 2):

based on following document, the output variable must be a table variable

```
<OUTPUT_CLAUSE> ::=
{
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> INTO { @table_variable | output_table } [ ( column_list ) ] ]
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> ]
}
```

[Output INSER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)